# Want to align three divs that contain lists horizontally

Tags: css, html

I am working with an html page in that i was stuck with some footer content.
 I want to align three `div` which contains some `lists` as horizontal

**like this**

[image]

**css**

```
.left-col {
    float: left;
    width:25%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;
}
.center-col {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height:100px;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    text-align:center;
}
.right-col {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:green;
    text-align: right;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="left-col"><ul><li>hai</li>
    <li>hai</li>
    <li>hai</li>
    <li>hai</li>
    <li>hai</li></ul></div>
<div class="center-col"><ul><li>hai</li>
    <li>hai</li>
    <li>hai</li>
    <li>hai</li>
    <li>hai</li></ul></div>
<div class="right-col"><ul><li>hai</li>
    <li>hai</li>
    <li>hai</li>
    <li>hai</li>
    <li>hai</li></ul></div>
```

please help me to fix this

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: can you provide your code please ?

Comment: I've close voted your question as you haven't shared the relevant code here, and if you haven't tried it yet, than please do it, and share the code here

Comment: look above edited my question!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the pre-defined height on the div's. Let them expand according to content. In center div you can give width to the ul and then make the text at center using **margin-left and margin-right** as auto.

```
.left-col {
    float: left;
    width:25%;
    background-color:blue;
}
.center-col {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;

}
.center-col ul
{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 100px;
}
.right-col {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    background-color:green;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ankur1990/H734d/

Also if you don't want to trouble yourself with width of ul then you can just go for margin-left to ul

```
.center-col ul
{
margin-left:100px //According to your need
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/R2ySb/)

Here are 2 solutions: with `float: left;` and `display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<footer>
<div class="list33">
    <ul>
        <li>hai</li>            
        <li>hai</li>
        <li>hai</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="list33">
    <ul>
        <li>hai</li>            
        <li>hai</li>
        <li>hai</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="list33">
    <ul>
        <li>hai</li>            
        <li>hai</li>
        <li>hai</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
footer .list33 {
width: 33.33%;
float: left;    
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Olavxxx/K8H25/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:table-cell;` so it would get horizontal aligned as well vertical as it's height grows:

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/HarishBoke/54uap/